# Write an SQL query to report the students (student_id, student_name) being “quiet” in ALL exams

Tags: sql, sql-server

-- A "quite" student is the one who took at least one exam and didn't score
neither the high score nor the low score.

-- Write an SQL query to report the students (student_id, student_name)
being "quiet" in ALL exams.

-- Don't return the student who has never taken any exam. Return the result
table ordered by student_id.

-- The query result format is in the following example.

**Student table:**

```
-- +-------------+---------------+
-- | student_id  | student_name  |
-- +-------------+---------------+
-- | 1           | Daniel        |
-- | 2           | Jade          |
-- | 3           | Stella        |
-- | 4           | Jonathan      |
-- | 5           | Will          |
-- +-------------+---------------+
```

**Exam table:**

```
-- +------------+--------------+-----------+
-- | exam_id    | student_id   | score     |
-- +------------+--------------+-----------+
-- | 10         |     1        |    70     |
-- | 10         |     2        |    80     |
-- | 10         |     3        |    90     |
-- | 20         |     1        |    80     |
-- | 30         |     1        |    70     |
-- | 30         |     3        |    80     |
-- | 30         |     4        |    90     |
-- | 40         |     1        |    60     |
-- | 40         |     2        |    70     |
-- | 40         |     4        |    80     |
-- +------------+--------------+-----------+
```

**Result table:**

```
-- +-------------+---------------+
-- | student_id  | student_name  |
-- +-------------+---------------+
-- | 2           | Jade          |
-- +-------------+---------------+
```

Is my solution correct?

```
--My Solution
Select Student_id, Student_name
From (
Select 
    B.Student_id, 
    A.Student_name,
    Score, 
    Max(Score) Over (Partition by Exam_id) score_max, 
    Max(Score) Over (Partition by Exam_id) score_min 
From
    Student A, Exam B 
Where 
    A.Student_ID = B.Student_ID
) T
Where   
    Score != Max_score or Score != Min_Score
Group by 
    student_id, student_name 
Having 
    Count(*) = (Select distinct count(exam_id) from exam)
Order by
    A.student_id
```

Comment: If you want to ensure whether your query is correct or wrong, then you can use sql fiddles. For instance: `https://dbfiddle.uk/`

Comment: *"Is my solution correct?"* Why not run it and find out? You're in a better position than us.

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: I'm unclear about the question: *"-- A "quite" student is the one who took at least one exam and didn't score neither the high score nor the low score."* Is that in all their exams or only in at least one of their exams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is correct but you need two changes in your query.

1. You have to change **Max** by **Min** in your score_min.

```
// ...
min(score) over (partition by exam_id) score_min,
max(score) over (partition by exam_id) score_max    
// ...
```

2. **Having** it should be like this:

```
having count(1) = 
(select count(distinct exam_id) from exam t2 
where t1.student_id = t2.student_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```sql
Select DISTINCT student_id, Name FROM [Table Score]
WHERE student_id NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT student_id FROM [Table Score]
WHERE Score = (Select Min(Score)FROM [Table Score]) OR Score=(Select MAX(Score)FROM [Table Score]) )
```

Comment: Why should they try it? What does it do? Can you [edit] your answer to explain your code?